# Jenkins cleanWs does not cleanup files due to permissions

Tags: docker, jenkins

We use Jenkins to (amongst other things) run a series of test jobs. For each test the necessary docker images and other objects are downloaded from a Nexus repository. The required containers and services are built and executed with docker-compose and maven. This all works and the tests run as desired.

After the test the workspace files and directories should be cleaned up. This should be possible using the `cleanWs` plugin. However, by default this uses the `deferredWipeout` option, which results in entire copies of the repository directories being left lying in the workspace in a directory called `<test-name>-ws-cleanup-<run-ID>`. These accumulate with time by adding @2, @3, etc. to the test name. Logically, I added the options `deleteDirs: true` and `disableDeferredWipeout: true`. This then produces an error like this:

```
hudson.AbortException: Cannot delete workspace: Unable to delete '/data/jenkins/workspace/XXXX-batch@2/XXX-batch-ant-core/target/classes/de/ubs/XXX/batch/ant/core/AbstractLicenseCheck.class'. Tried 3 times (of a maximum of 3) waiting 0.1 sec between attempts.
```

This happens, because, for reasons which are not entirely clear to me, some of the sub-directories and files created have owner "root" with permissions set to 755 (i.e. rwxr-xr-x). These are typically the target directories created by the maven build, though I am not sure if there aren't others. There are several thousand files involved, so I haven't checked them all... yet. I might end up having to do that.

To get around the problem, a cleanup service definition was added to the *docker-compose.yml* file which defines the build an test services. The following commands were tested:

```
command: rm -rf * && rm -rf /opt/test/*
```

This caused an obscure error message about an invalid option "c" for the rm command. (??) Otherwise no effect. After checking some other Stack Overflow question, I tried this:

```
command: sh -c "rm -rf * && rm -rf /opt/test/*"
```

This produces no error, but also doesn't have the desired effect, either. Using `--verbose` option on the `docker-compose run` yields:

```
2021-03-09 08:29:26 compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': '',
2021-03-09 08:29:26  'Args': ['rm', '-rf', '*', '&&', 'rm', '-rf', '/opt/test/*'],
2021-03-09 08:29:26  'Config': {'AttachStderr': True,
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'AttachStdin': True,
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'AttachStdout': True,
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'Cmd': ['rm', '-rf', '*', '&&', 'rm', '-rf', '/opt/test/*'],
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'Domainname': '',
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'Entrypoint': ['/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh'],
2021-03-09 08:29:26             'Env': ['TZ=Europe/Berlin',
2021-03-09 08:29:26                     'CONTAINERED=true',
2021-03-09 08:29:26 ...
```

This, frankly, tells me nothing other that the command was somehow recognized.

Another approach was to try changing the permissions on the files and directories to 777:

```
command: echo "<password>" | su -c "chmod -R 777 ."
```

This works when executed on the console, but has no effect when used in the *docker-compose.yml* or the pipeline groovy script used by Jenkins.

I do not know what else I can try and would be grateful for any hints. I am happy to provide further details if required.

Comment: Have you installed jenkins using docker? What is your agent which you have declared in the pipeline?

Comment: @Nisarg Shah: The script in question is non-declarative, so no agent is defined. It's just a series of nodes and stages. Jenkins is not run in a docker container, either.

Comment: Okay. Are you using this command - `cleanup { cleanWs() }`? This will clean your whole workspace along with tmp files.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah: Yes, of course, that was the original form. But, as mentioned, the default is deferredWipeout. So nothing was cleaned up. When the command was changed to cleanWS(deleteDirs: true, disableDeferredWipeout: true) then the error "Cannot delete workspace" was produced.

Comment: Can you try running `sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace`? Maybe there can some files which are there of root user or something. I had similar experience and this command had helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a compound issue.

Firstly, changing the owner and group as suggested by Nisarg Shah was not an option, because inside the container there is no user called Jenkins.

The solution in the end was to set the permissions on the files in the test to `777` (i.e. rwxrwxrwx) by issuing a command as root. In the end the command in the docker-compose.yml looked like this:

```
command: sh -c 'echo "<root-password>" | su root -c "chmod -R 777 ."'
```

To get to this stage required a lot of experimentation, because the command is parsed by different processes including docker-compose and the shell.

If you're not using docker-compose and you wish to do the same thing in the groovy pipeline script, then the following should work (it did for me in one of the many experiments):

```
sh 'echo "<root-password>" | su root -c "chmod -R 777 ."'
```

Using either of the preceding approaches, and by adding the following stage in the groovy pipeline script, Jenkins was able to perform the desired cleanup:

```
stage('cleanup') {
    cleanWs deleteDirs: true, disableDeferredWipeout: true
}
```

Hope this helps someone with similar issues.

P.S. On our system, jenkins is not in the sudoer group. Hence the use of "su root". If your jenkins is a sudoer, then sudo would, of course, also do the trick.